# React Native Vision Camera Storage and Background Capabilities

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I have some questions about [react-native-vision-camera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/) capabilities:

1. When I take photos or record videos, files are stored inside some temporal location. How can i save them in user media directory?
2. Can I keep recording (on background) after abandoning react-navigation screen, going to other app or locking the phone?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: After taking photos I move them with react-native-fs but I think they cannot leave App Sandbox in case of iOS.

Comment: Ah ok so no direct write to storage. Thats a shame, i'll post here if I find anything

Comment: Both photos and videos seems to be created inside some temporal folder inside app directory. They remain there after you close and reopen app but are overwitten as soon as you take/record more photos/videos.